# How do I inject radio elements into the panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to do a dynamic injection into the panel. I'm not sure if this problem is because the panel is hidden when I call this function or if I am injecting the data properly.

The control group I am targeting is in the panel - hidden when I run this function it updates the values but becomes frozen and unusable even though it is identical to a working model I have locally. The radio group somehow remains locked on the first radio element and I am unable to change the value on click after I run this function.

It is in the sidepanel [filter] > https://jsbin.com/gugepeboci/edit?html,js,output

HTML (jQuery Mobile changes this structure on page and wraps radio elements in `.ui-controlgroup-controls`)

```
<fieldset id="colour-radio-group" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-iconpos="right">
    <legend></legend>
        <input type="radio" name="colour-choice" id="radio-choice-5" value="Any Colour" checked="checked">
        <label for="choice-1">Any Colour</label>
        <input type="radio" name="colour-choice" id="radio-choice-6" value="orange">
        <label for="choice-2">Green</label>
        <input type="radio" name="colour-choice" id="radio-choice-7" value="yellow">
        <label for="choice-3">Orange</label>
        <input type="radio" name="colour-choice" id="radio-choice-8" value="violet">
        <label for="choice-4">Purple</label>
</fieldset>
```

Javascript and jQuery

```
 // Data to be inserted
 var myArray = ["red", "blue", "black"];

 //Empty radio group for new data
 $("#colour-radio-group .ui-controlgroup-controls").empty();

 // Loop array and add data dynamically
 for (var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {

     var index = x + 2;

     if (x == 0) {

         // inject default
         $(`<div class="ui-radio ui-mini">
               <label for="colour-choice-1" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-right ui-radio-on ui-first-child">Any Colour</label>
               <input type="radio" name="colour-choice" id="colour-choice-1" value="default" checked="checked" data-cacheval="false">
            </div>`).appendTo('#colour-radio-group .ui-controlgroup-controls');

     }

     // inject data
     $(`<div class="ui-radio ui-mini">
           <label for="colour-choice-` + index + `" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-right ui-radio-off">`+ myArray[x] +`</label>
           <input type="radio" name="colour-choice" id="colour-choice-` + index + `" value="` + myArray[x] + `" data-cacheval="false">
        </div>`).appendTo('#colour-radio-group .ui-controlgroup-controls');

 }

// fix UI problem
$('#colour-radio-group .ui-controlgroup-controls').children().last().children('label').addClass('ui-last-child');
```

I have kind of just winged this problem and kept digging myself a hole, any advice?

Comment: please create jsfiddle example !!

Comment: https://jsbin.com/gugepeboci/edit?html,js,output jsfiddle isn't working for some reason

Comment: your jsbin is wrong!!  there is a left prime symbol in click event. I create a new jsbin and fixed prime issue but I don't know is this you want ? take a look  and tell me is that you want ?? [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/quyelujefi/edit?html,js)

Comment: @TaiwanHotDog and your jsBin does what exactly?

Comment: @Scott may I ask what is `.ui-controlgroup-controls`? Some imaginary DOM element?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sir ! It's your show time. lol

Comment: your jsbin does nothing but break the radio group even more to a point where it isn't even displaying its labels, @RokoC.Buljan clearly if you can read html you will know what I'm talking about take a look at the page source jquery mobile adds some html also and wraps `.ui-controlgroup-controls` around the radio items

Comment: @Scott so I was almost right :D lol -  missed that, thx.

Comment: The way you're appending content isn't advisable. Anyway, to fix your issue, replace last line with this `// fix UI problem
$('.mypanels').enhanceWithin();`.

Comment: @Omar why not? I have used your enhanceWithin() suggestion instead of trigger() with m-ba's answer, thanks - works

Comment: Too much work. Your code should be minimal for easier debugging. The less code, the better. When you encounter closed doors, use `.enhanceWithin()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only add plain-html (instead of jquery-mobile stuff).

And trigger `create` to `#colour-radio-group` does the job.

https://jsbin.com/nijezovali/1/edit?html,js,output

Edit: if you want, you can add jquery mobile stuff.

```
$('#colour-radio-group .ui-controlgroup-controls').trigger("create");
```

is enough.

Comment: `.trigger()` is obsolete.

Comment: @Omar so is JQM ;-)

Comment: @Omar ;-) Welcome back!

Comment: @PhillHealey Thank you mate :) I have forgotten how to code. It took me 15 mins to answer this question. I'm no longer into that field, anymore. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a better way to dynamically generate a new controlgroup. Note that this solution is only to create brand new radio buttons controlgroup.

```
// Data to be inserted
var myArray = ["red", "blue", "black"];

$('#click').click(function() {

  // Remove existing controlgroup
  $(".mypanels .ui-controlgroup").remove();

  // Create a new one
  var rbuttons = $("<fieldset/>", {
    id: "colour-radio-group",
    "data-role": "controlgroup",
    "data-mini": true
  });

  // Add it
  rbuttons.appendTo(".mypanels");

  // Loop array and add data dynamically
  for (var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
    if (x == 0) {

      // inject default
      rbuttons.append($("<input/>", {
        type: "radio",
        name: "colors-panel",
        id: "color-d",
        checked: true
      })).append($("<label/>", {
        for: "color-d",
        text: "Any Color"
      }));

    }

    // inject data
    rbuttons.append($("<input/>", {
      type: "radio",
      name: "colors-panel",
      id: "color-" + x
    })).append($("<label/>", {
      for: "color-" + x,
      text: myArray[x]
    }));
  }

  // Apply jQM enhancement
  $("#colour-radio-group").controlgroup();
});
```

> **[Demo](https://jsbin.com/logaseg/edit?js,output)**